# Creating Certificate from base64 encoded string failing in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, x509certificate, x509certificate2, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to create an `X509Certificate2` from a base64 encoded string. This code I have added to a sample Azure function.
Locally the code works and I can create a cerificate object from bas364 encoded string, however when publishing to Azure I get an exception
`Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore`
Following https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30658
I have kept app service plan as '(P1v2: 1)' which is not shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Use WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` app setting in your azure function the specified certificates accessible to your Windows hosted app in the Windows certificate store, in [Current_User\Your_user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/local-machine-and-current-user-certificate-stores).

In your code, access the certificate by the certificate thumbprint. Like `certificateThumbprint = "<your certificate thumbprint>";`

> Note: App Service inject the certificate paths into Windows containers. like variables `WEBSITE_PRIVATE_CERTS_PATH`, `WEBSITE_INTERMEDIATE_CERTS_PATH`, `WEBSITE_PUBLIC_CERTS_PATH`, and `WEBSITE_ROOT_CERTS_PATH`. Make sure you have to reference the certificate path with the environment variables instead of hardcoding the certificate path.

If still, you are facing the same issue you can add the `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE=1` app settings in your app. The error says that the certificate not accessible for specific user. It will fix your problem.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#make-the-certificate-accessible) for more information